# How to write a Bazel test rule using a provided tool rather than a rule-built one?

Tags: bazel, starlark

I have a test tool (roughly, a diffing tool) that takes two inputs, and returns both an output (the difference between the two inputs), and a return code (0 if the two inputs are matching, 1 otherwise). It's built in Kotlin, and available at `//java/fr/enoent/phosphorus` in my repo.

I want to write a rule that tests that a file generated by something is identical to the reference file already present in the repository. I tried something with `ctx.actions.run`, the problem being that my rule, having `test = True` set, needs to return an executable *built by that rule* (so not a tool provided to the rule). I then tried to wrap it in a shell script following the [example](https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/blob/master/rules/test_rule/line_length.bzl), like this:

```
def _phosphorus_test_impl(ctx):
    output = ctx.actions.declare_file("{name}.phs".format(name = ctx.label.name))
    script = phosphorus_compare(
        ctx,
        reference = ctx.file.reference,
        comparison = ctx.file.comparison,
        out = output,
    )

    ctx.actions.write(
        output = ctx.outputs.executable,
        content = script,
    )

    runfiles = ctx.runfiles(files = [ctx.executable._phosphorus_tool, ctx.file.reference, ctx.file.comparison])
    return [DefaultInfo(runfiles = runfiles)]

phosphorus_test = rule(
    _phosphorus_test_impl,
    attrs = {
        "comparison": attr.label(
            allow_single_file = [".phs"],
            doc = "File to compare to the reference",
            mandatory = True,
        ),
        "reference": attr.label(
            allow_single_file = [".phs"],
            doc = "Reference file",
            mandatory = True,
        ),
        "_phosphorus_tool": attr.label(
            default = "//java/fr/enoent/phosphorus",
            executable = True,
            cfg = "host",
        ),
    },
    doc = "Compares two files, and fails if they are different.",
    test = True,
)
```

(`phosphorus_compare` is just a macro generating the actual command.)

However, this approach has two issues:

- The output can't be declared this way. It's not linked to any action (and Bazel is complaining about it). Maybe I don't really need to declare an output for a test? Does Bazel make anything in the test folder available when the test fails?
- The runfiles necessary to run the tool don't seem to be available when the test runs:
  `java/fr/enoent/phosphorus/phosphorus: line 359: /home/kernald/.cache/bazel/_bazel_kernald/58c025fbb926eac6827117ef80f7d2fa/sandbox/linux-sandbox/1979/execroot/fr_enoent/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/tools/phosphorus/tests/should_pass.runfiles/remotejdk11_linux/bin/java: No such file or directory`

Overall I feel like using a shell script is just adding an unnecessary indirection, and losing some context (e.g. tools' runfiles). Ideally, I would just use `ctx.actions.run` and rely on its return code, but it doesn't seem to be an option as a test apparently needs to generate an executable. What would be the correct approach to write such a rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, generating a script is the correct approach, it's (as far as I understood) impossible to return some kind of pointer to a `ctx.actions.run`. A test rule *needs* to have an executable output.

Regarding the output file that the tool is generating: there's no need to declare it, at all. I just need to make sure that it's generated in `$TEST_UNDECLARED_OUTPUTS_DIR`. Every single file in this directory will be added to an archive called `output.zip` by Bazel. This is (partly) documented [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/test-encyclopedia.html#test-interaction-with-the-filesystem).

Concerning the runfiles, well, I had the tool's binary, but not its own runfiles. Here is the fixed rule:

```
def _phosphorus_test_impl(ctx):
    script = phosphorus_compare(
        ctx,
        reference = ctx.file.reference,
        comparison = ctx.file.comparison,
        out = "%s.phs" % ctx.label.name,
    )

    ctx.actions.write(
        output = ctx.outputs.executable,
        content = script,
    )

    return [
        DefaultInfo(
            runfiles = ctx.runfiles(
                files = [
                    ctx.executable._phosphorus_tool,
                    ctx.file.reference,
                    ctx.file.comparison,
                ],
            ).merge(ctx.attr._phosphorus_tool[DefaultInfo].default_runfiles),
            executable = ctx.outputs.executable,
        ),
    ]

def phosphorus_test(size = "small", **kwargs):
    _phosphorus_test(size = size, **kwargs)

_phosphorus_test = rule(
    _phosphorus_test_impl,
    attrs = {
        "comparison": attr.label(
            allow_single_file = [".phs"],
            doc = "File to compare to the reference",
            mandatory = True,
        ),
        "reference": attr.label(
            allow_single_file = [".phs"],
            doc = "Reference file",
            mandatory = True,
        ),
        "_phosphorus_tool": attr.label(
            default = "//java/fr/enoent/phosphorus",
            executable = True,
            cfg = "target",
        ),
    },
    doc = "Compares two files, and fails if they are different.",
    test = True,
)
```

The key part being `.merge(ctx.attr._phosphorus_tool[DefaultInfo].default_runfiles)` in the returned `DefaultInfo`.

I also made a small mistake about the configuration, as this test is intended to run on the target configuration, not host, it's been fixed accordingly.